# Оптимальный ли конфиг php-fpm?

Tags: php, linux, веб-сервер

Вебсервер: физический сервер состоящий из 6 ядер, 128 гб озу и ssd диски.
Часто жалуются на 502 во время обращения к сайту.
В лог медленных скриптов часто падает запрос с подключением к бд. И из-за этого появляется как раз 502.

php.ini:

```
memory_limit = 512M
```

Конфигурационный файл php-fpm:

```
pm.max_children = 150
pm.start_servers = 36
pm.min_spare_servers = 24
pm.max_spare_servers = 48
pm.process_idle_timeout = 5s;
```

На данный момент php-fpm работает через сокет.
Может будут какие-нить рекомендации.

Comment: А какой смысл ковырять конфиг php-fpm, если проблема в медленном подключении к базе данных? Используйте persistent connection (для mysql) или pgbouncer (для postgres) и будет вам счастье.

Comment: Что за persistent conection?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/features.persistent-connections.php